# WebGL unable to initialize shader program

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, glsl, webgl

I am attempting to write a pair of shaders for WebGL which will allow me to render a color cube.  However, when I attempt to open the file, I receive the error "unable to initialize the shader program".  How might I go about debugging this and where should I start to look in the shaders?  I've been able to do some debugging with more specific errors but I don't know where to begin with this kind of general message.  Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

  varying lowp vec3 vColor;

  varying highp vec3 vLighting;





  void main(void) {

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor * vLighting, 1.0);



  }

</script>



<!-- Vertex shader program -->



<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

  attribute highp vec3 aVertexNormal;

  attribute highp vec3 aVertexPosition;

  attribute highp vec4 aVertexColor;



  uniform highp mat4 uNormalMatrix;

  uniform highp mat4 uMVMatrix;

  uniform highp mat4 uPMatrix;



  varying highp vec3 vLighting;

  varying highp vec4 vColor;



  void main(void) {

    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);



    //Apply the coloration to the cube

    vColor = aVertexColor;



    // Apply lighting effect



    highp vec3 ambientLight = vec3(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);

    highp vec3 directionalLightColor = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.75);

    highp vec3 directionalVector = vec3(0.85, 0.8, 0.75);



    highp vec4 transformedNormal = uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 1.0);



    highp float directional = max(dot(transformedNormal.xyz, directionalVector), 0.0);

    vLighting = ambientLight + (directionalLightColor * directional);

  }

</script>
```

Here's the code to compile the shaders:

```
    //
// initShaders
//
// Initialize the shaders, so WebGL knows how to light our scene.
//
function initShaders() {
  var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
  var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

  // Create the shader program

  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

  // If creating the shader program failed, alert

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert("Unable to initialize the shader program.");
  }

  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

  vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute);

  vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexColorAttribute);

  vertexNormalAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexNormal");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexNormalAttribute);
}

//
// getShader
//
// Loads a shader program by scouring the current document,
// looking for a script with the specified ID.
//
function getShader(gl, id) {
  var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

  // Didn't find an element with the specified ID; abort.

  if (!shaderScript) {
    return null;
  }

  // Walk through the source element's children, building the
  // shader source string.

  var theSource = "";
  var currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;

  while(currentChild) {
    if (currentChild.nodeType == 3) {
      theSource += currentChild.textContent;
    }

    currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
  }

  // Now figure out what type of shader script we have,
  // based on its MIME type.

  var shader;

  if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
    shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
    shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  } else {
    return null;  // Unknown shader type
  }

  // Send the source to the shader object

  gl.shaderSource(shader, theSource);

  // Compile the shader program

  gl.compileShader(shader);

  // See if it compiled successfully

  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert("An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    return null;
  }

  return shader;
}
```

-----------------------EDIT---------------------------------
I have made changes according to the suggestions below and now the screen is completely blank when I open the file.  Previously, the black canvas was displayed but now the screen is white.  I would appreciate any advice that you can give.  Thanks!

```
    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

  varying lowp vec4 vColor;

  varying mediump vec3 vLighting;


  void main(void) {

    gl_FragColor = vColor * vec4(vLighting, 1.0);
  }

</script>



<!-- Vertex shader program -->



<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

  attribute mediump vec3 aVertexNormal;

  attribute mediump vec3 aVertexPosition;

  attribute mediump vec4 aVertexColor;



  uniform mediump mat4 uNormalMatrix;

  uniform mediump mat4 uMVMatrix;

  uniform mediump mat4 uPMatrix;



  varying mediump vec3 vLighting;

  varying mediump vec4 vColor;



  void main(void) {

    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);



    //Apply the coloration to the cube

    vColor = aVertexColor;



    // Apply lighting effect



    mediump vec3 ambientLight = vec3(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);

    mediump vec3 directionalLightColor = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.75);

    mediump vec3 directionalVector = vec3(0.85, 0.8, 0.75);



    mediump vec4 transformedNormal = uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 1.0);



    mediump float directional = max(dot(transformedNormal.xyz, directionalVector), 0.0);

    vLighting = ambientLight + (directionalLightColor * directional);

  }

</script>
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, the only thing I see wrong here is your unconditional use of `highp` in a fragment shader. WebGL does not guarantee support for this, and you need to check the pre-processor definition `FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH` first. If it is undefined, use `mediump` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Andon, I have tried replacing all instances of highp with mediump and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share the code for loading your shaders?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should update your framework so when it gets an error compiling it queries WebGL for the error and prints it? After compiling the shader if it's not successful call `gl.getShaderInfoLog` as in

```
// Compile the shader
gl.compileShader(shader);

// Check the compile status
var compiled = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
if (!compiled) {
  // Something went wrong during compilation; get the error
  console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
```

You should do something similar when linking as in

```
gl.linkProgram(program);

// Check the link status
var linked = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
if (!linked) {
  // something went wrong with the link
  console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
```

When I tried it with my framework I got this error from WebGL

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
var program = twgl.createProgramFromScripts(
    gl, ["shader-vs", "shader-fs"], ["a_position"]);
```

```html
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

  varying lowp vec3 vColor;

  varying highp vec3 vLighting;





  void main(void) {

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor * vLighting, 1.0);



  }

</script>



<!-- Vertex shader program -->



<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

  attribute highp vec3 aVertexNormal;

  attribute highp vec3 aVertexPosition;

  attribute highp vec4 aVertexColor;



  uniform highp mat4 uNormalMatrix;

  uniform highp mat4 uMVMatrix;

  uniform highp mat4 uPMatrix;



  varying highp vec3 vLighting;

  varying highp vec4 vColor;



  void main(void) {

    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);



    //Apply the coloration to the cube

    vColor = aVertexColor;



    // Apply lighting effect



    highp vec3 ambientLight = vec3(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);

    highp vec3 directionalLightColor = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.75);

    highp vec3 directionalVector = vec3(0.85, 0.8, 0.75);



    highp vec4 transformedNormal = uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 1.0);



    highp float directional = max(dot(transformedNormal.xyz, directionalVector), 0.0);

    vLighting = ambientLight + (directionalLightColor * directional);

  }

</script>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

```
Error in program linking:Varyings with the same name but different type,
or statically used varyings in fragment shader are not declared in 
vertex shader: vColor
```

Which seems to point out the error.

Comment: Thank you gman, I have added the code I used for compiling the shaders to the post.  When I get off work, I will attempt to use your suggestion to pinpoint the error in my machine and see if I can fix it.

Comment: Well so for the code you posted above you can see in the error in the answer above it says `vColor` is declared differently in both shaders. And looking at the code you posted it's declared as `vec3` in one and `vec4` in the other.

Comment: I have attempted to correct the error but now the screen is completely white when I open the file.  I have posted the revised shaders above and would appreciate any advice.  Thanks!